# Run a single migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Is there an easy way to run a single migration? I don't want to migrate to a certain version I just want to run a specific one.

Comment: Is this something that you ran once as a migration because it happened to be needed, then turns out to be a useful query that might need to get run a number of times? perhaps you should refactor the contents of the migration into a model or other object, then have the migration reference that new location. Then you can simply execute the new object at your lesure by invoking ruby on the command line.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You can just run the code directly out of the ruby file:

```
rails console
>> require "db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb"
>> AddFoos.new.up
```

Note: Very old versions of rails may require `AddFoos.up` rather than `AddFoos.new.up`. If your migration has a "change" method, you need to run `AddFoos.new.change`.

An alternative way (without IRB) which relies on the fact that require returns an array of class names:

```
script/runner 'require("db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb").first.constantize.up'
```

Note that if you do this, it won't update the `schema_migrations` table, but it seems like that's what you want anyway.

Additionally, if it can't find the file you may need to use `require("./db/..."` or try `require_relative` depending on your working directory

Comment: Sometimes you need a './' in front of the require path, and it definitely doesn't update the schema_migrations.

Comment: `script/runner 'require("db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb").first.constantize.up'`

This seems like a cool trick. But `require` now returns either true or false. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I had to create an instance of the migration object before I could call up. e.g. `AddFoos.new.up`

Comment: So, to sum up for Rails 3.2: `require "./db/migrate/db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb"` then `AddFoos.new.up`

Comment: If your migration uses `change` instead of `up` and `down`, you'll need to run `AddFoos.new.migrate(:up)`

Comment: @DonWerve thank you for this comment! I was following the root answer and getting nothing, your comment got me what I needed.

Comment: In rails 4, you can call `AddFoos.new.change`

Comment: Use ```require "#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb"```

Comment: just change `require` to `require_relative` in newer versions of Ruby 2.  I don't see any other answers recommending that.  You don't have to change the relative path string at all - hence - require_relative :)

Comment: perfect solution !!

Comment: The answer should be updated with comment made by @Beardo.

Comment: for newer versions may need to call `change` instead of `up`

Answer (score 509):

Assuming fairly recent version of Rails you can always run:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20090408054532
```

Where version is the timestamp in the filename of the migration.

**Edit: At some point over the last 8 years (I'm not sure what version) Rails added checks that prevent this from running if it has already been run.  This is indicated by an entry in the `schema_migrations` table.  To re-run it, simply execute `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20090408054532` instead.**

Comment: This will run migrations up to that version. I was looking for a way to run just a specific migration.

Comment: Actually the command is rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version

Comment: redo runs the down-method of the given migration and the up method after that. up runs only the up-method, and I think that is exactly what the asking person wants.

Comment: In rails 3.1.3, redo struggles sometimes with older migrations. require + #up works great.

Comment: 'up' appears to not run if the database schema version is later than the migration in question, which can happen when merging another person's changes, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I used this for down with `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=XXX`

Comment: for any noobs like me wondering: rake db:migrate:status to get the timestamp. (someone pls correct me if i'm wrong.)

Answer (score 122):

If you want to [run a specific migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations), do

```
$ rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

If you want to run migrations [multiple times](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back), do

```
# use the STEP parameter if you need to go more than one version back
$ rake db:migrate:redo STEP=3
```

If you want to run a **single** migration **multiple** times, do

```
# this is super useful
$ rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20080906120000
```

(you can find the version number in the filename of your migration)

---

**Edit:** You can also simply rename your migration file, Eg:

`20151013131830_my_migration.rb` -> `20151013131831_my_migration.rb`

Then migrate normally, this will treat the migration as a new one (usefull if you want to migrate on a remote environment (such as staging) on which you have less control.

**Edit 2**: You can also just nuke the migration entry in the database. Eg:

```
rails_c> q = "delete from schema_migrations where version = '20151013131830'"
rails_c> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(q)
```

`rake db:migrate` will then rerun the `up` method of the nuked migrations.

Comment: Both "up" and "redo" didn't work for me, but deleting the row in schema_migrations was perfect.

Answer (score 33):

If you've implemented a `change` method like this:

```
class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
  end
end
```

You can create an instance of the migration and run `migrate(:up)` or `migrate(:down)` on an instance, like this:

```
$ rails console
>> require "db/migrate/20090408054532_add_part_number_to_products.rb"
>> AddPartNumberToProducts.new.migrate(:down)
```

Comment: This also applies even if you're using `up` and `down`.

Comment: worked for me to run the migration AddPartNumberToProducts.new.migrate(:up)
but strange thing is that this  AddPartNumberToProducts.up does not worked

Answer (score 19):

This are the steps to run again this migration file "20150927161307_create_users.rb"

1. Run the console mode. (rails c)
2. Copy and past the class which is in that file to the console.

   ```
   class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :users do |t|
         t.string :name
         t.string :email
         t.timestamps null: false   end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Create an instance of the class `CreateUsers`: `c1 = CreateUsers.new`
4. Execute the method `change` of that instance: `c1.change`

Comment: just require the file with the class, e.g. in the console: `require "./db/migrate/20150927161307_create_users.rb"` instead of copy & pasting.  You can then run the class the same way by instantiating and calling the method defined in the class `CreateUsers.new.change`.

Comment: perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 17):

As of `rails 5` you can also use `rails` instead of `rake`

**Rails 3 - 4**

```
# < rails-5.0
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20160920130051
```

**Rails 5**

```
# >= rails-5.0
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20160920130051

# or

rails db:migrate:up VERSION=20160920130051
```

Comment: it also guess what you need with
`rails db:migrate VERSION=20160920130051`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to run it from console, this is what you are looking for:

```
$ rails console
irb(main)> require "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/migrate/XXXXX_my_migration.rb"
irb(main)> AddFoo.migrate(:up)
```

I tried the other answers, but requiring without `Rails.root` didnt work for me.

Also, `.migrate(:up)` part forces the migration to rerun regardless if it has already run or not. This is useful for when you already ran a migration, have kinda undone it by messing around with the db and want a quick solution to have it up again.

Answer (score 15):

If you're having trouble with paths you can use

```
require Rails.root + 'db/migrate/20090408054532_add_foos.rb'
```

Answer (score 5):

Please notice that instead of `script/runner`, you may have to use `rails runner` on new rails environments.

Answer (score 5):

Method 1 :

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000
```

Method 2:

In Rails Console
 1. Copy paste the migration class in console (say add_name_to_user.rb)
 2. Then in console, type the following

```
Sharding.run_on_all_shards{AddNameToUser.up}
```

It is done!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like at least in the latest Rails release (5.2 at the time of writing) there is one more way of filtering the migrations being ran. One can pass a filter in a `SCOPE` environment variable which would be then used to select migration files.

Assuming you have two migration files `1_add_foos.rb` and `2_add_foos.run_this_one.rb` running

```
SCOPE=run_this_one rails db:migrate:up
```

will select and run only `2_add_foos.run_this_one.rb`. Keep in mind that all migration files matching the scope will be ran.