# How can I rollback a specific migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema, database-schema, rollback

I have the [migration file](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) `db\migrate\20100905201547_create_blocks.rb`.

How can I specifically rollback that migration file?

Comment: Does this address the issue?  You'll just need to do `Class.down`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753919/run-a-single-migration-file

Comment: Every information on migrations [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: Do you want to roll back only that single specific migration (even if there are newer migrations that come after it)? Or do you want to roll back the database to the state it was in before that migration, and any subsequent migrations, were applied?

Comment: many times this command 'rails db:rollback'

Answer (score 1770, accepted):

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

Is a way to do this, if the migration you want to rollback is the last one applied. You can substitute 1 for however many migrations you want to go back.

For example:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=5
```

Will also rollback all the migration that happened later (4, 3, 2 and also 1).

To roll back all migrations back to (and including) a target migration, use: (This corrected command was added *after* all the comments pointing out the error in the original post)

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20100905201547
```

In order to rollback *only one* specific migration (*out of order*) use:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

Note that this will NOT rollback any interceding migrations -- only the one listed. If that is not what you intended, you can safely run `rake db:migrate` and it will re-run only that one, skipping any others that were not previously rolled back.

And if you ever want to migrate a single migration out of order, there is also its inverse `db:migrate:up`:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20100905201547
```

Comment: "In order to rollback to specific version" - doesn't the command that follows only rollback a specific migration, rather than rolling all the way back to that version?

Comment: "In order to rollback to specific version use..."

**This answer is incorrect!** This will rollback the migration in isolation as explained by other answers.

Comment: WARNING: I made this mistake: only use rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547 to rollback IN ISOLATION!!! one migration file.  This is mentioned in the comment above, but I missed it.

Comment: Another word of warning - don't ever do `STEP=-1`. I did that once and it went mad, rolling back everything. Not nice! This was Rails 4.2 - I guess it may be fixed by now.

Comment: Wrote an article in my blog about migrations, that explains how and when to use these commands: https://railsguides.net/polish-rails-migrations/

Comment: Nice blog but why do you guess the migration's nationality?! :D

Comment: On rails 5.2 this did not also rollback the target migration for me. As mentioned in 'rake db:migrate VERSION=20100905201547'

Comment: Don't forget you can use `rake db:migrate:status` to see all the specific migrations and their status!

Comment: In rails 6.1.3.2 `rails db:migrate VERSION=` does *not* run the down for the migration given by VERSION

Answer (score 955):

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

will roll back the specific file.

---

To find the version of all migrations, you can use this command:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Or, simply the prefix of the migration's file name is the version you need to rollback.

---

See [the Ruby on Rails guide entry](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations) on migrations.

Comment: Definitely the preferred answer in my opinion.

Comment: Would this rollback migration be pushed across all remote servers, eg. Heroku? Would it be better to create a new migration file just to undo the specific changes?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you roll back a specific migration and do not want it to re-migrate on upcoming rake tasks, then delete the migrate file as well.

Comment: Yup. This is way better than stepping.  Stepping has its place, but if you just want to fix a single migration (and don't care about losing the data in the table, obviously) this is the stuff of legends.

Comment: Note: it seems that if the up migration never succeeded but have only been partially executed, the down does nothing.

Comment: Even 

    rake db:migrate VERSION=old_version

works!

Comment: Can I simply remove the migration file once performing this migration down method?

Comment: @nerith, it's probably true only for databases which doesn't support Transactional DDL.
MySQL doesn't support Transactional DDL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html
PostreSQL does: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis

So if your migration on MySQL database is broken then you have manually to delete part of migration that succeeded.

Comment: Another observation regarding @BradGreens comment. If you do want to remove the migration file, and it has already been deployed, you'll want to roll back production/staging before you commit the code with the removed file. Otherwise you won't be able to rollback/migrate:down.

Comment: Note that this does not roll back all migrations up to and including the specified migration; rather, it rolls back just that single specific migration (leaving any subsequent migrations still applied).

Comment: @AdamT you shouldn't be rolling back migrations in production in general. If the migration slipped that far then it is preferrable to create a new migration wich reverses the previous migration. It is a hellsih mess to try and rollback migrations in prod. Something might end up accidentally rerunning it before you have time to get rid of the file. Also surely some of your colleagues may have by now also run the migration. You need to then instruct them to remember to roll it back before pulling lates code changes.. and ofc also manaually fix the staging env and what not.. not a good idea.

Answer (score 70):

To rollback the last migration you can do:

```
rake db:rollback
```

If you want to rollback a specific migration with a version, you should do:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=YOUR_MIGRATION_VERSION
```

For example, if the version is 20141201122027, you will do

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141201122027
```

to rollback that specific migration.

Answer (score 41):

You can rollback your migration by using `rake db:rollback` with different options. The syntax will be different according to your requirements.

If you want to rollback just the last migration, then you can use either

```
rake db:rollback
```

or

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

If you want rollback number of migrations at once, then you simply pass an argument:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

where `n` is number of migrations to rollback, counting from latest migration.

If you want to rollback to a specific migration, then you should pass the version of the migration in the following:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxx
```

where xxxxx is the version number of the migration.

Comment: adding :down is not working though, the correct answer is without down

Answer (score 29):

Use:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=your_migrations's_version_number_here
```

The version is the numerical prefix on the migration's file name.

**How to find the version**:

Your migration files are stored in your `rails_root/db/migrate` directory. Find the appropriate file up to which you want to rollback and copy the prefix number.

For example:

File name: `20140208031131_create_roles.rb`

Then the version is `20140208031131`.

Comment: The simplest way to find the migration id is to run `rake db:migrate:status`

Answer (score 20):

Rolling back the last migration:

```
# rails < 5.0
rake db:rollback

# rails >= 5.0
rake db:rollback
# or
rails db:rollback
```

Rolling back the last `n` number of migrations

```
# rails < 5.0
rake db:rollback STEP=2

# rails >= 5.0
rake db:rollback STEP=2
# or
rails db:rollback STEP=2
```

Rolling back a specific migration

```
# rails < 5.0
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547

# rails >= 5.0
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
# or
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

Answer (score 14):

To rollback the last migration you can do:

```
rake db:rollback
```

If you want to rollback a specific migration with a version you should do:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=YOUR_MIGRATION_VERSION
```

If the migration file you want to rollback was called `db/migrate/20141201122027_create_some_table.rb`, then the VERSION for that migration is `20141201122027`, which is the timestamp of when that migration was created, and the command to roll back that migration would be:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20141201122027
```

Answer (score 13):

To roll back **all migrations up to a particular version** (e.g. `20181002222222`), use:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20181002222222
```

(Note that this uses `db:migrate` -- not `db:migrate:down` as in other answers to this question.)

Assuming the specified migration version is older than the current version, this will roll back all migrations up to, but not including, the specified version.

For example, if `rake db:migrate:status` initially displays:

```
  (... some older migrations ...)
  up      20181001002039  Some migration description
  up      20181002222222  Some migration description
  up      20181003171932  Some migration description
  up      20181004211151  Some migration description
  up      20181005151403  Some migration description
```

Running:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20181002222222
```

Will result in:

```
  (... some older migrations ...)
  up      20181001002039  Some migration description
  up      20181002222222  Some migration description
  down    20181003171932  Some migration description
  down    20181004211151  Some migration description
  down    20181005151403  Some migration description
```

Reference: *[Migrate or revert only some migrations](https://makandracards.com/makandra/845-migrate-or-revert-only-some-migrations)*

Answer (score 7):

### If you are using Ruby on Rails 3

Step: 1 (check the last migration)

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

Step: 2 (roll back the last migration)

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

Now, you can revert the migration with safety *one by one*.

### For a specific migration

`rails d migration <migration_name>`

### For reverting multiple migrations

`bundle exec rake db:rollback STEP=n`

where `n` is how many migrations you want to rollback.

Example: `bundle exec rake db:rollback STEP=5`

Comment: For multiple migrations, it only works if your migrations are in a following order and the last you applied, not if you want to rollback specific ones

Answer (score 6):

If it is a reversible migration and the last one which has been executed, then run `rake db:rollback`. And you can always use the version.

For example, if the migration file is *20140716084539_create_customer_stats.rb*, the rollback command will be:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140716084539
```

Answer (score 6):

A migration file looks like this,

```
 20221213051020_my_migrations
```

In this case, the model name should be `MyMigration`. The migration ends with a plural word, so it ends with `migrations`.

To roll back this particular migration, you have to understand that the first part of the migration name (number in front of the migration name) is the migration number.

To *roll back* this migration, just open the terminal and write,

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=migration_number
```

So finally, you have to actually type in the terminal to roll back this particular migration,

> *Write the below command on terminal to rollback a particular migration, upper command is just to explain you*

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20221213051020
```

Just remember that each migration has a different migration number, so watch carefully and copy paste or type manually.

Answer (score 5):

Migrations change the state of the database using the command

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

We can undo a single migration step using

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

To go all the way back to the beginning, we can use

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

As you might guess, substituting any other number for 0 migrates to that version number, where the version numbers come from listing the migrations sequentially.

Comment: What is this "bundle"? The OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*); can somebody else chime in?

Answer (score 5):

You can run `down` migration command to rollback the migration like below:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, in rails 5 it's quite easy

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

or

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

It was modified to handle both the same way.
Then just pick which *version* you want to roll back
and then run

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=2013424230423
```

Make sure VERSION is all capital letters.

If you have a problem with any step of the migration or stuck in the middle simply, go to the migration file and comment out the lines that were already migrated.

Comment: I highlight the hint for command **rake db:migrate:status** . . . It's great for overview to see the current execution state of the migration files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rollback and migrate you can run:

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

That's the same as:

```
rake db:rollback
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

**In addition**:

When a migration you deployed long ago does not let you migrate a new one.

I work in a larger Ruby on Rails application with more than a thousand of migration files. And, it takes a month for us to ship a medium-sized feature. I was working on a feature and I had deployed a migration a month ago, and then in the review process the structure of migration and filename changed, now I try to deploy my new code, the build failed saying:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "my_new_field" of relation "accounts" already exists

None of the above-mentioned solutions worked for me, because the old migration file was missing and the field I intended to create in my new migration file already existed in the database. The only solution that worked for me is:

1. I `scp`ed the file to the server
2. I opened the `rails console`
3. I required the file in the [IRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) session
4. then `AddNewMyNewFieldToAccounts.new.down`

And then I could run the deploy build again.

Answer (score 2):

I found these steps most useful.

To check for status, run `rails db:migrate:status`. Then you'll have a good view of the migrations you want to remove.

Then, run `rails db:rollback` to revert the changes one by one. After doing so, you can check the status again to be fully confident.

Next, if you want to remove or delete. Run `rails d migration <migration_name>`. This would clean up the versions you created.

After that's done, you can proceed to making new changes.

Answer (score 1):

For a multiple databases configurations *(RoR >= v6)*, you must append the database name in the command, like:

- `rails db:rollback:primary`, where **primary** is the name of the database in your `config/databases.yml` file, to roll back the last migration. You can make usage of the STEPS attribute here, as usual.
- `rails db:migrate:down:primary VERSION=your_migration_timestamp`, to revert only the provided migration version. Here **primary** is the name of the database too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert from the last migration, use the **rake db:rollback** command. It's working fine for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode, you can create the following [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

```
  {
      "label": "rollback open migration",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "rails db:migrate:down VERSION=$(basename ${file} .rb | cut -d '_' -f 1)"
  },
```

Running the task will rollback the migration open in the file editor