# How to rollback a specific table in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I tried 'rake db:rollback VERSION=' but it didn't work. Can somebody tell me how to rollback a specific table?  Pls help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3, how to roll back a Migration file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647685/rails-3-how-to-roll-back-a-migration-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<timestamp>
```

Comment: not working for heroku: heroku run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<timestamp>