# Rails Populating a polymorphic association through migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, polymorphic-associations

Hey all i am trying to write a migration for a polymorphic association that i made this morning.

upon creating the new column for the members table called `management_type` since members already belonged to a management i have the `management_id` for free. I added the `has_many :members, :as => :management` to the various management models that have members

This allows me to add members to both `AlphaManagement` and `BravoManagement` but all the existing members where only on `AlphaManagement` as i just added `BravoManagemnent`. so all the existing members have a null value for management_type. i want to just create a migration that will go through each tuple and then add the `AlphaManagement` association to the management_type column but only if its null. so that on later migrations i don't change them all to `AlphaManagement` by accident

i see that i could have done something like this to set the default

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.references :attachment, :polymorphic => {:default => 'Photo'}
end
```

but if i have already created the table how could i set a default value for the association through a migration?

**EDIT** - just so you can see what i have done

1.migration

```
class AddingManagementTypeToMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :members, :management_type, :string
  end

  def down
    remove_column :members, :management_type
  end
end
```

1. added `belongs_to :management, :polymorphic => true` to the members class. note managers directors and executives all inherit from member.
2. the way managements where run have changed but we want to keep legacy reports so we need both the older management and new management models. so in both i added `has_many :members, :as => :management`

ran migrations. Now adding members to either `Alpha` or `Bravo` managements is as easy as bravo_management.members.new(:name => 'rob')

Comment: You could always do a rake db:rollback, edit your migration and re migrate.

Comment: i would but there is several migrations that have now happend after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue previously.  You just want to rollback the specific migration using

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=1234123412341234`

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647685/rails-3-how-to-roll-back-a-migration-file), but note this is not the accepted answer in that particular question even though it probably makes a lot sense.

Comment: thats really cool i didnt know you could reverse a specific version very nice. i eventally had to roll back and re-implement quite a bit. i wish i had found this before.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier, could have saved you some trouble.  At least it will be good for future reference, hopefully help someone else too.