# Roll back a specific migration without rolling back other migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, command-line, migration

I mistakenly ran the second to last db migration wrong, but the last migration is fine. Now I want to roll back my second to last migration without reverting the last migration. Please share your knowledge with me and others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647685/rails-3-how-to-roll-back-a-migration-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxx` where xxx is your migration version number for more [see this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations)

Answer (score 8):

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20140804301246
```

Comment: i think to rollback command until that migration, and delete that migration then again done all work carefully, i know its bad approach but will it works ?

Comment: Thats also a way of doing it :). But you have to be careful if the code is shared with other developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your Migration file **`version number`** to **`rollback`** that Migration.

You can achieve it by either of these

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=your_file_version
```

**OR**

```
rake db:rollback:up VERSION=your_file_version
```

Comment: i think to rollback command until that migration, and delete that migration then again done all work carefully, i know its bad approach but will it works ? and thanks @pavan

Comment: @m_Awais If you have done wrongly only that migration,then you can simply rollback it and do necessary changes correctly and again migrate it.

Answer (score 2):

simple answer i found is

```
rake db:rollback STEP=X
```

where X is the number of migration you want to play with(rollback).
LIKE

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```