# Is it possible that a rails migration file would be common for 2 different git branches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, migration, git-branch

I created a new branch for new changes

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch
```

Then I made a new migration and it created a new migration file. I decided to cancel this migration so I did:

```
git checkout master
git status
```

and I have noticed that I have this new migration file in the master branch.
**Why did it happen?**

Comment: When you switched branches to master, your uncommitted changes (the new file) came with you.

Comment: @Jon, I find your answer very helpful. If you want add your answer as an answer to my question I will, I will vote and mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem ... 2 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you've switched branches with uncommitted changes in your local branch. These uncommitted changes were then listed as uncommitted changes against the new branch after changing branches.

There are various options open to you to get back to a clean state depending on the situation you're in. Notably, these two are worth looking into:

`git reset --hard` and `git clean`

Comment: Thanks that was helpful for me!

Comment: My problem was that I switched from `my-new-branch` to `master branch` without committing my changes(migration file).

Answer (score 0):

If you did migrated that migration file(rake db:migrate), it'll makes changes in DB which you cannot revert by checking out to master. You'll need to do migration rollback.

[Migration Revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647685/rails-3-how-to-roll-back-a-migration-file).

Else just

> git stash

and go back to master, everything will be old.