# How to rollback specific Databases with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6 has Multiple Databases with Active Record.

My question is what if I want to rollback a migration in one specific database?

something like this is not working:

```
rails db:rollback:primary
```

Link to "Multiple Databases with Active Record" documentation:
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

Comment: One option is to set `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` which has precidence over any settings from database.yml. Not very elegant but works.

Answer (score 5):

try run `rails db:migrate:down:secondary VERSION=yourdbversionnumber`.

I realized that this command are available when i try to run `rails db:migrate:down` and then rails give [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTk4j.png) in the terminal. Also, maybe for further details on `rails db:migrate:down`,refer to [How to rollback a specific migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647685/how-to-rollback-a-specific-migration])