# rollback index argument error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

This is my model :

```
class CreateStoreComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :store_comments do |t|
      t.text :comment
      t.references :store_post, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :store_comments, [:user_id, :created_at]

  end
end
```

I have added the index after generating the model, and then I migrated the model. And when I write in the console :

```
rails db:rollback
```

I get this error:

```
D:\ruby_projects\myapp-main>rails db:rollback
== 20231023131530 CreateStoreComments: reverting ==============================
-- remove_index(:store_comments, [:user_id, :created_at])
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

No indexes found on store_comments with the options provided.


Caused by:
ArgumentError: No indexes found on store_comments with the options provided.

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

There was another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74816468/argumenterror-no-indexes-found-on-likes-with-the-options-provided) that showed the same problem, but I didn't understand the solution or there wasn't sufficient answer.

**Edit**
This is the schema for the store_comments

```
create_table "store_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "comment"
    t.integer "store_post_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index "\"store_id\", \"user_id\", \"created_at\"", name: "index_store_comments_on_store_id_and_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["store_post_id"], name: "index_store_comments_on_store_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_store_comments_on_user_id"
  end
```

**steps** I did to create this table:
I first wrote this in the console

```
rails generate model StoreComment comment:text store_post:references user:references
```

I then added this line in the migration file before migrating

```
add_index :store_comments, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

finally, I wrote in the console

```
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Did you run the migration before or after adding the index clause? Also post your `db/schema.rb` or equivalent please.

Comment: This migration will actually run both ways without problems. The issue is more likely that you modified the migration after migrating it which is never a good idea. Just create another migration next time - they should be deleted after being migrated across environments so it doesn't matter if you get it perfectly right the first time.

Comment: Since you're doing this locally you can temporarily comment out `add_index` in the migration, rollback, uncomment the line and run migrations again. As other commenters said it's best not to change migrations after you already ran them

Comment: @SiimLiiser I have added the schema in the post. And I ran the migration after adding the index clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at your `schema.rb` in detail and comparing it to your migration, line by line.

```rb
# create_table :store_comments do |t|
create_table "store_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  # t.text :comment
  t.text "comment"
  # t.references :store_post, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.integer "store_post_id", null: false
  # t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.integer "user_id", null: false
  # t.timestamps
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  # ???
  # this index is not added by the migration
  t.index "\"store_id\", \"user_id\", \"created_at\"", name: "index_store_comments_on_store_id_and_user_id_and_created_at"
  # t.references :store_post, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.index ["store_post_id"], name: "index_store_comments_on_store_post_id"
  # t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_store_comments_on_user_id"
end
```

Almost every line is accounted for, except for one.

```rb
t.index "\"store_id\", \"user_id\", \"created_at\"", name: "index_store_comments_on_store_id_and_user_id_and_created_at"
```

This is a line in the schema (your database), that is not created by the given migration.

```rb
add_index :store_comments, [:user_id, :created_at]
```

This is a line in your migration that doesn't have a corresponding index in the schema (your database).

You probably changed the index definition after running the migration.

Now when you rollback, Rails is trying to delete the index that should have been created, but is not and is failing.

Comment out the `add_index` line, `rails db:rollback`, comment it back in, `rails db:migrate`.

And try not to change migrations after they have run.