# rake db:migrate manually providing one file with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

Somehow my test environment forgot to copy over several migrations. In order to troubleshoot, I want to call certain migration files by hand.

Is there a rake db:migrate option or trick that allows me to pass in a directory full of migrations that should be ran? Or even a specific migration file that will be ran?

These migrations are not present under `db/migrate/`, but rather in another gems' migration folder (`/home/ber/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@xxx/gems/spree_auth-1.0.0/db/migrate/`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [generate your migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) with a specific version then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753919/run-a-single-migration-file) will help you with that.

From post:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20090408054532
```

Where `VERSION=` is set to whatever comes from your generation.

Answer (score 2):

try running this

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

you will find a table with all your migrations

choose the version you would like to migrate or unmigrate 
then

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=201853073732
```

Notice that this won't work if you are stuck in mid migrations if you are you have to comment out the lines that were already migrated 
Good luck