# Rails 3.2: Invoking up\down from another migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I'm looking to invoke another migration in a similar fashion to that of generators.
Basically if you have a create table then at some point of time in the future you're no longer using the table and you want a migration to call `up` and `down` exactly opposite to those of the original create migration.
If it's possible then I'd create a generator something like

```
rails g reverse_migration CreateModel
```

and then the result is something like

```
class ReverseCreateModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #call to create model down
  end
  def down
    #call to create model up
  end
end
```

I don't want any workaround kind of way and rather explicitly duplicate code and keep the ability for a clean migration and roleback.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A migration is just a Ruby file, so you can `require` it:

```
require "./db/migrate/20120117195557_create_model.rb"

class ReverseCreateModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    CreateModel.new.down
  end

  def down
    CreateModel.new.up
  end
end
```

If your original migration uses `change`, you must use `CreateModel.new.migrate(:down)` and `CreateModel.new.migrate(:up)`.

In my case, when using `migrate(direction)` generates more output when migrating:

```
==  ReverseCreateModel: migrating ======================================
==  CreateModel: reverting =============================================
(...)
==  CreateModel: reverted (0.0018s) ====================================

==  ReverseCreateModel: migrated (0.0019s) =============================
```

instead of:

```
==  ReverseCreateModel: migrating ======================================
(...)
==  ReverseCreateModel: migrated (0.0019s) =============================
```

This answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/754316/183791